# Setting HW clock with upstart

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I have a small embedded board (Jetson TX1) that runs Ubuntu 14.04.  The carrier board the chip is mounted to doesn't have a provisions for a backup battery or supercap so the clock loses time whenever it's unplugged (and there typically won't be internet connected to set it that way).  I have a battery powered I2C clock module that I have used before.  The clock requires a kernel module that I have successfully compiled and installed (I adapted instructions found [here](http://www.jetsonhacks.com/2015/08/13/real-time-clock-rtc-nvidia-jetson-tk1/) to the TX1.) After the system is fully booted, I can set the system clock via:

```
$> echo ds3231 0x68 | sudo tee /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-1/device/new_device
$> sudo hwclock -s -f /dev/rtc2
```

which works great.  I would like to have this done automatically on boot and it seems upstart is the right tool.  In fact there is already a task /etc/init/hwclock.conf to do this with the built-in RTC (i.e. the one that loses it's time because it has no battery), so I figure I can just hijack it.  It's contents are:

```
# hwclock - adjust system clock and timezone
#
# The hwclock task adjusts the system clock when the hardware clock is
# set to localtime (e.g. when dual-booting with Windows), and also
# ensures that the system timezone is set so that timestamps are written
# to FAT devices.

description "adjust system clock and timezone"

start on starting mountall

task

script
    . /etc/default/rcS
    [ "$UTC" = "yes" ] && tz="--utc" || tz="--localtime"
    [ "$BADYEAR" = "yes" ] && badyear="--badyear"
    exec hwclock --systz $tz --noadjfile $badyear
end script
```

I have changed it to:

```
start on starting mountall

task

script
    /bin/echo "ds3231 0x68" > /sys/class/i2c-dev/i2c-1/device/new_device
    /sbin/hwclock -sf /dev/rtc2
end script
```

but on restarting, the system time is not set and if I look in /var/logs/upstart/hwclock.log this message is given:

```
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method
hwclock: Use the --debug option tosee the details of our search for an access method.
```

which to me sounds like its running the task before the kernel module is loaded.  I have tried other events such `start on filesystem` and `start on runlevel [2345]` to no avail.  however after the system boots I can type just `sudo hwclock -sf /dev/rtc2` and it works.

UPDATE: I just tried the event `start on runlevel [23456]` and that actually seems to work. I'm not sure why adding the 6 to the runlevels makes it work since I thought run level 6 was for rebooting?  Is this the best event or is there a better one to make sure the clock gets set reliably?